# Reinitializing variable in php to NULL

Tags: php, post, controller, initialization, yii2-advanced-app

I'm writing a simple gamePage. My `Controller` method looks like this:

```
$model = new Game143();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->verifyAnswers();
        return $this->render('Game143-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        $model->initGame(1, 2);
        return $this->render('Game143', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

The `else` is the important bit. The `initGame` method is passed the starting level and the max number of levels, so I'm iterating 2 times with random digits and everything works fine.

In my init method I set the value:

```
public function initGame($level, $numEx) {
    $this->maxLevel = $numEx; // normally 10
    $this->thisLevel = $level; //normally 1
```

I also did some output. This works fine and my variable is saved as `2`.

In the `if` method of the controller my variable is suddenly set to `NULL`?!
Because of this even my results are `NULL`, because my iteration is `<=maxLevel`. Anyone know why this happens?

In `verifyAnswers();` my given and initialized maxLevel is `NULL`.
Iterating not possible:

```
for(; $this->thisLevel <= $this->maxLevel; $this->thisLevel++) {
```

If i hardcode the `maxLevel` everything works fine also.

In the view (Working with yii-2):

```
for($model->thisLevel = 1; $model->thisLevel <= $model->maxLevel; $model->thisLevel++) {
$out .= "\n";
$out .= Html::activeHiddenInput($model,"digit1[$model->thisLevel]");
$out .= "\n";
$out .= Html::activeHiddenInput($model,"digit2[$model->thisLevel]");
$out .= "\n";
$out .= "\n";
$out .= "<h3>Level $model->thisLevel</h3>\n";   
$out .= "<h3>max $model->maxLevel</h3>\n";
$out .= "\n";
$out .= "<div class=\"row aufgabenFeld\">";
$out .= "<div align=\"right\" class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 wallLabel \">";
$out .= $model->digit1[$model->thisLevel];
$out .= "</div>";

$out.="<div id='myField__<?php echo $model->thisLevel; ?>' class=\"col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 wall\">\n";
$out .= $form->field($model, "proposal[$model->thisLevel]")->label(false);
$out .= "</div>";

$out .= "<div  align=\"left\" class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 wallLabel \">"; //id test xD
$out .= $model->digit2[$model->thisLevel];
$out .= "</div>";
$out .= "</div>";

$out .= "<div><br></div>";
```

In the 'submitView':

```
foreach ($model->proposal as $key=>$value){
$out .= "<li><h4>Aufgabe $key</h4>";
$out .= $model->digit1[$key];
$out .= " ";
$out .= $model->proposal[$key];
$out .= " ";
$out .= $model->digit2[$key];
$out .= $model->maxLevel[$key];
$out .= "</li>";
}
```

Comment: can't actually understand.. which variable is set to null ?

Comment: where you check `maxLevel` variable? show this code.